# Remove existing data points after graph update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have made a function that should remove existing data points (depending on a query), but the previous data points still exist on the graph. How can I remove the existing data points before the transition with the new data points?

```
var dot = svg
.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.state); } )
.attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.number); } )
.attr("r", 5)
.style("fill", "blue")

function update(selectedGroup) {

var updateData = data.filter(function(d){ 
  if ( selectedGroup === "VIC" ) {
    return d.state === "VIC"
  } else if (selectedGroup === "NSW") {
  return d.state === "NSW"
  } else {
    return data
  }
});

dot
  .data(updateData)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(+d.state) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(+d.number) })

}

d3.select("#VIC")
.on("click", function(d, i) {
  update("VIC");
});

d3.select("#NSW")
.on("click", function(d, i) {
  update("NSW");
});

d3.select("Both")
.on("click", function(d, i) {
  update("data");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not reuse `dot` selection. Selections are immutable, and thus you should always reselect in cases where elements had potentially changed.
2. Inside update method, you don't have no `enter` at all, thus you won't be creating new needed elements if your new data is of bigger size than previous.
3. Old elements that do not have matching item in data array are accessed using `.exit()` selection. You can remove them by calling `.remove()` on it

```js
var data = [{
  state: 'VIC',
  number: 2
}, {
  state: 'NSW',
  number: 5
}]

var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg').attr('width', 300).attr('height', 60);
var x = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(['VIC', 'NSW'])
  .range([50, 250]);
  
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([10, 50]);

function update(selectedGroup) {

  var updateData = data.filter(function(d) {
    if (selectedGroup === "VIC") {
      return d.state === "VIC"
    } else if (selectedGroup === "NSW") {
      return d.state === "NSW"
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
  

  var dot = svg
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(updateData);
    
  dot.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.state);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.number);
    })
    .attr("r", 0)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .merge(dot)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.state)
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(+d.number)
    });

  dot.exit()
    .transition()
    .attr('r', 0)
    .remove();

}

d3.select("#VIC")
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    update("VIC");
  });

d3.select("#NSW")
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    update("NSW");
  });

d3.select("#Both")
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    update("data");
  });
  
update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
<button id="VIC">VIC</button>
<button id="NSW">NSW</button>
<button id="Both">Both</button>
```